# How to create an object of the same type than another one at runtime?

Tags: java

I have a method that accepts a MyObject interface as a parameter. In this method, I want to create an object of the same runtime implementation class. Like this

```
public void myMethod(MyObject myObject) {
    MyObject localObject = new ...??//instantiate a concrete MyObject like the parameter myObject.
    doSomething(localObject);
}

public void doSomething(MyObject myObject){//do something with this object}
```

I don't have any kind of clone() implementation on MyObject nor prototyping.

Maybe I'm doing something totally not-java?

Comment: If you don't have a clone()/some kind of copy method, you can use reflection for copying.

Comment: I just found myObject.getClass().newInstance() if that's what you mean, but it's deprecated. Any better way?

Comment: `myObject().getClass().getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();`

Comment: @dan1st that's should be the accepted answer...thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1: copy method

If `MyObject` is a (probably abstract) class/interface, you could create a copy method:

```java
public interface MyObject{
    MyObject newOfSameType();
}
```

```java
public abstract class MyObject{
    public abstract MyObject newOfSameType();
}
```

Implementations could then override the `copy()`-method:

```java
public class MyConcreteObject implements MyObject{
    @Override
    public MyConcreteObject newOfSameType(){
        MyConcreteObject copy=new MyConcreteObject();
        //You could do setup stuff, here
    }
}
}
```

### Option 2: Reflection

Another way would be to use reflection to create an object of the same type:

```
MyObject localObject;//set it to something
Class<? extends MyObject> cl=localObject.getClass();
Constructor<? extends MyObject> constructor=cl.getConstructor();//expect no-args-constructor
//Constructor<? extends MyObject> constructor=cl.getConstructor(cl);//expect copy constructor
//Constructor<? extends MyObject> constructor=cl.getConstructor(Parameter.class);//expect a constructor with a parameter of a class called Parameter, varargs work, here
MyObject instance=constructor.newInstance();
//MyObject instance=constructor.newInstance(instance);//copy constructor
//MyObject instance=constructor.newInstance(yourParameter);//parameter of type Parameter, varargs work here
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create an object according to the concrete implementation on runtime.
   If you have 2 concrete implementations, MyObject1 and MyObject2, use something like:

   ```
    public static MyObject copyObject(MyObject myObject) {
        if (myObject == null) return null;
        if (myObject instanceof MyObject1) {
             return new MyObject1();
        }
        if (myObject instanceof MyObject2) {
             return new MyObject2();
        }
        return null;
    }
   ```
2. Reflection.